# Utilizando timestamp em campos diferentes

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Possuo um campo timestamp em uma tabela postgres. gostaria de tratar, no delphi, a data em um dbedit e a hora em outro, existe essa possibilidade?? Nos testes que realizei, até consigo alterar os valores mas quando saio, por exmplo do dbedit q mantem a data, ele altera a hora e o mesmo acontece quando saio do dbedit da hora, ele altera a data.

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas de se fazer isso é não utilizar componentes DBWare, e utilizar os eventos de DataSet `AfterScroll` e `BeforePost` para atualizar seus campos que não são DBWare.

Considerando o campo `DataHoraBanco` você pode fazer o seguinte:

Prieiro crie 2 campos sem utilizar componentes DB (`TEdit, TDateTimePicker, TMaskEdit`, etc)

```
dteDataForm
edtHoraForm
```

No seu dataset no evento `AfterScroll` preencha:

```
procedure Form1.DataSetonAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  dteDataForm.Date := Trunc(DataSet.FieldByName('DataHoraBanco').AsDateTime );
  edtHoraForm.Text := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', DataSet.FieldByName('DataHoraBanco').AsDateTime);
end;
```

E no evento `BeforePost` faça:

```
procedure Form1.DataSetonAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet.FieldByName('DataHoraBanco').AsDateTime := dteDataForm.Date +
    StrToTime(edtHoraForm.Text);
end;
```

Lembrando que o tipo TDateTime do delphi é um Double e por isso a função Trunc extrai a parte inteira (data) e na soma, é utilizado o sinal `+` para somar a parte decimal equivalente aos minutos e segundos.

Answer (score 0):

No seu Select você pode criar dois campos "virtuais", um para hora e outro para data. Fazendo um cast para data e outro para hora, a partir do campo original(timestamp).
No evento BeforePost do componente você concatena os dois valores para o campo original.

Exemplo:

```
Select Cast(CampoTimeStamp as Date) as Campo_Data, Cast(CampoTimeStamp as Time) as Campo_Hora, CampoTimeStamp From...
```

No evento before post seria algo assim:

```
DataSet['CampoTimeStamp'] := DataSet['Campo_Data'] + DataSet['Campo_Hora'];
```